# Android: App response gets slow after several operations

Tags: android, performance

I am developing a POS app for a restaurant. Things work fine, except that after some time the app gets very sluggish. The response appears to be 2 seconds late, and then we need to restart the application.
Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Each time when a food category is selected, e.g COLD DRINK, I remove the previous food items below it and add new items according to the selected category.

So, to me it seems that when I frequently add and remove views from the panel (GridLayout), the app gets slower and slower.

I simply do `gridLayout.removeAllViews();` to remove all views.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this please?

Comment: GridLayout is a bad choice for dynamic grid/list... why don't you use RecyclerView/ListView?

Comment: It sounds to me like every time you are populating the grid, you are adding a list of new items to show without ever removing the old items. Then as you keep adding new sets of items the list gets ridiculously large and you are running low on memory.

Comment: @Selvin yea.. it seems i'll have to replace gridLayout with some recycle view and then try it.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe. no noChin, i am not adding more data to my list.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the views, but it don't necessary destroy then, so they continue occupying memory resources.

It's better to use some kind of list with an adapter, like ListView or RecyclerView, witch you can add or remove the views and they will only occupy memory when showing (or all that is showing more two).

You can do something like :

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();        

        listaItems.add(yourString); // call that ever you have to add new itens

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

to remove do something like :

```
listaItems.remove([INDEX]);
itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yep, you can create an custom adapter with any layout inside and populate text views inside it